# OpenLayers 4 last position with cookie

Tags: openlayers

I'm implementing the option to return to the last position with cookies but I don't know how to set the last resolution.

Here part of the code:

```
if (setPos) {
  var setPos = sessionStorage.getItem('mappos').split(',');
  view.centerOn( [setPos[0], setPos[1]] , map.getSize(), [($(window).innerWidth()/2), ($(window).innerHeight()/2)]);

 view.setResolution(setPos[2]);

} else {
    var tmp = getUserPrefs();
    if (tmp != null) {
      var urlpos = window.location.search.replace( "?", "" );

    if (urlpos.search('defpos') == -1) {
            sDefPos = tmp;
            var setPos = sDefPos.split(',');
        }
  } else {
      var setPos = twSettings.defpos.split(',');
  }
}
```

view.setResolution() it works but then if I move the zoom the map disappears and I have to delete the browser history to have it back.

There is a way to set the last zoom level and maintain the resolutions array I have in the view and be able to continue exploring the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was:

view.setResolution(parseFloat(setPos[2]));

It seems that centerOn accept the number in the array but setResolution doesn't recognize that number as a number.